# Can't get the full width of input in Laravel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am working on extending my bootstrap template into my laravel project. I have problem with input width. In my project I can't get full width of input in my column. Only difference is form in my laravel project. How I can fix this?

[image: Full width of input]

My bootstrap HTML (working):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" value="Short Url">
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
  </div>
```

[image: Not full width of input]

My template in Laravel (Input doesn't have full width):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="input-group">
      <form class="navbar-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://localhost:8000" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" value="C5RbH20lMX79fI8TuI4SkVKu6QPQEyw2QgSDGOQc" name="_token">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Enter your adress" name="url">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `<form>` outside `.input-group`

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <form class="navbar-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://localhost:8000" method="POST">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="hidden" value="C5RbH20lMX79fI8TuI4SkVKu6QPQEyw2QgSDGOQc" name="_token">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Enter your adress" name="url"> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" value="Short Url">
      </span>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/40/)**